# Powershell: Logical operator -or doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell, logical-operators

I have the problem to understand how -or works. I want to exclude the Active Directory Helper Service and the Full-text Filter service.
Follwing example doesn't work:

```
get-service -DisplayName "*SQL*" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -notlike "*Active*" -or $_.DisplayName -notlike "*Filter*"}
    
MsDtsServer100              SQL Server Integration Services 10.0
MSOLAP$DFNCS08TST1          SQL Server Analysis Services (DFNCS08TST1)
MSSQL$DFNCS08TST1           SQL Server (DFNCS08TST1)
MSSQL$DFNCS08TST2           SQL Server (DFNCS08TST2)
MSSQL$DFNCS08TST3           SQL Server (DFNCS08TST3)
MSSQLFDLauncher$DFNCS08TST1 SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (DFNCS08TST1)
MSSQLFDLauncher$DFNCS08TST2 SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (DFNCS08TST2)
MSSQLFDLauncher$DFNCS08TST3 SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (DFNCS08TST3)
MSSQLServerADHelper100      SQL Active Directory Helper Service
SQLAgent$DFNCS08TST1        SQL Server Agent (DFNCS08TST1)
SQLAgent$DFNCS08TST2        SQL Server Agent (DFNCS08TST2)
SQLAgent$DFNCS08TST3        SQL Server Agent (DFNCS08TST3)
    SQLBrowser              SQL Server Browser
    SQLWriter               SQL Server VSS Writer
```

but -and works:

```
get-service -DisplayName "*SQL*" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -notlike "*Active*" -and $_.DisplayName -notlike "*Filter*"}
    
MsDtsServer100              SQL Server Integration Services 10.0
MSOLAP$DFNCS08TST1          SQL Server Analysis Services (DFNCS08TST1)
MSSQL$DFNCS08TST1           SQL Server (DFNCS08TST1)
MSSQL$DFNCS08TST2           SQL Server (DFNCS08TST2)
MSSQL$DFNCS08TST3           SQL Server (DFNCS08TST3)
SQLAgent$DFNCS08TST1        SQL Server Agent (DFNCS08TST1)
SQLAgent$DFNCS08TST2        SQL Server Agent (DFNCS08TST2)
SQLAgent$DFNCS08TST3        SQL Server Agent (DFNCS08TST3)
SQLBrowser                  SQL Server Browser
SQLWriter                   SQL Server VSS Writer
```

I know I could have gotten the same result with just get-service -DisplayName "SQL Server*" but my question is about why -or doesn't work as expected.

From the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.1):
-or Logical OR. TRUE when either
-and Logical AND. TRUE when both

Changing the -notlike to -like it works as expected with -or.
Maybe you are able to help me understand why it behaves this way.

Thank you very much and kind regards,
Olaf

Comment: _"I want to exclude the Active Directory Helper Service **and** the Full-text Filter service"_, so `-and` is the way to go.. `(-not ($_.DisplayName -like "*Active*" -or $_.DisplayName -like "*Filter*"))` would also work, same as 
`$_.DisplayName -notmatch 'Active|Filter'`

Comment: If you say `X not A or X not B` then that will *always* be true. If `X` is `A` then it is not `B`. If `X` is `B`, then it's not `A`. If `X` is `C` then it's neither `A` or `B`. In all cases, the logical expression resolves to true.